# What is current best practices for browser detection

Tags: php, jquery, html, cross-browser

I have a php routine that takes HTML, does some processing on it, and presents it back out.

The problem is that depending on the browser there may or may not be an extra 
 added to the output.

If I can get the browser I can code for this issue.  However, I am confused by what I've found so far as to how to get what browser is being used.

The JQuery documentation says don't use the $browser property. other people say don't use navigator.userAgent.  So what am I supposed to use?

Thank you!

[Edit: Thank you all for your great answers.  I learned something new and would like to mark all replies as an answer but since I can only select one I am going to choose Justin's because of his reply that my issue is probably styling.]

Comment: Since 1.9 you cannot user $.browser. What exactly do you THINK you need to test and why>

Comment: Do you need that information on Client Side or at Server Side ?

Comment: I always find [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html) & [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/support.html) helpful

Comment: `navigator.userAgent` means writing your own regex / functionality which is a pain in the backside to keep up to date - let someone else / some other library do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best practice for browser detection is **not to use it**.

You should be using feature detection instead. Check out the suite of tests in [jQuery.support](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/).

Comment: How do I detect the feature of the browser adding an extra <br>?

Comment: @user390480 - Are you sure the browser is actually adding an extra <br> element rather than just styling the elements differently? That sounds like a styling issue, not a code issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you really, really, really want to know the browser, you get use get_browser() (http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php). I do not recommend it because it's not only slow and required constant updating of your file, it's also a bad practice to give the user different output based on different browsers.

It's a better idea to fix the bugs and issues with javascript/css afterwards for browsers other than chrome/firefox.

Answer (score 1):

The current best practice is to use feature detection.  There are entire libraries devoted to this such as [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) and [`$.support`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/) as part of the jQuery API. The idea is to check for a missing *feature* and fallback to secondary support all the way down to just providing a message that that feature is not supported.

The mantra among web developers now is **don't do browser detection**, but I think that's unrealistic in some cases.  There are plenty of times where you may want to say "You are using Internet Explorer 7!" or the like, and that obviously requires a guess at the user agent string via php's `get_browser()` or `navigator.userAgent` on the JavaScript side.  I also had an issue with a web app where IE7 & IE8 used too much memory to handle a certain load of data -- that's obviously not a "feature" that can be detected.

You can also use feature detection to guess at specific browsers.  For example, IE7 doesn't have `window.localStorage`.

The point is that if you want to try to guess at what the browser is you're going to have to accept a certain possibility of error.